# How to update Helm chart / Kubernetes manifests without "latest" tags?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm think I'm about to reinvent the wheel here. I have all the parts but am thinking: Somebody must have done this (properly) before me.

We have a a jenkins CI job that builds `image-name:${BRANCH_NAME}` and pushes it to a registry. We want to create a CD job that deploys this `image-name:${BRANCH_NAME}` to kubernetes cluster. And so now we run into the problem that if we call `helm upgrade --install` with the same `image-name:${BRANCH_NAME}` nothing happens, even if `image-name:${BRANCH_NAME}` now actually refers to a different sha256 sum. We (think we) understand this.

How is this generally solved? Are there best practices about this? I see two general approaches:

1. The CI job doesn't just create `image-name:${BRANCH_NAME}`, it also creates a unique tag, e.g. `image-name:${BRANCH_NAME}-${BUILD_NUMBER}`. The CD job never deploys the generic `image-name:${BRANCH_NAME}`, but always the unique `image-name:${BRANCH_NAME}-${BUILD_NUMBER}`.
2. After the CI job has created `image-name:${BRANCH_NAME}`, its SHA256 sum is retrieved somehow (e.g. with `docker inspect` or [`skopeo`](https://github.com/containers/skopeo) and helm is called with the SHA256 sum.

In both cases, we have two choices. Modify, commit and track a `custom-image-tags.yaml` file, or run helm with `--set` parameters for the image tags. If we go with option 1, we'll have to periodically remove "old tags" to save disk space.

And if we have a single CD job with a single helm chart that contains multiple images, this only gets more complicated.

Surely, there must be some opinionated tooling to do all this for us.

What are the ways to do this without re-inventing this particular wheel for the 4598734th time?

## `kbld` gets me some of the way, but breaks helm

I've found [`kbld`](https://carvel.dev/kbld/), which allows me to:

```
helm template my-chart --values my-vals.yml | kbld -f - | kubectl apply -f -
```

which basically implements 2 above, but now helm is unaware that the chart has been installed so I can't `helm uninstall` it. :-( I'm hoping there is some better approach...

Comment: If you do `kubectl apply -f -`, did you know that you can do `kubectl delete -f -`

Comment: We have a tool with Reliza Hub that allows you to parse your helm values file into new values file based on definitions from Reliza Hub and sets expected sha256 digests - section 7.2. and 7.3. of documentation here - https://github.com/relizaio/reliza-cli#72-use-case-replace-tags-on-deployment-templates-to-inject-correct-artifacts-for-gitops-using-instance-and-revision.

Note, this particular feature is new and we're working on better documenting it, meanwhile you can reach me via discord to discuss how to implement it - https://discord.gg/UTxjBf9juQ

Comment: @Matt: Thanks, yeah, I did know that. While I'm not crazy about Helm, it is *the* tool. If using helm, I'd like to use it fully, so my deployments are managed by Help. Who knows, I'll perhaps become wiser...

Comment: @taleodor: We're looking for open source, command-line tools exclusively, and we need them to be hosted on-premise, so it doesn't look like a good fit. Thanks for the pointer though. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

`kbld` can also be used "fully" with helm...

Yes, the [docs](https://carvel.dev/kbld/) suggest:

```
$ helm template my-chart --values my-vals.yml | kbld -f - | kubectl apply -f -
```

But this also works:

```
$ cat kbld-stdin.sh

#!/bin/bash
kbld -f -

$ helm upgrade --install my-chart --values my-vals.yml --post-renderer ./kbld-stdin.sh
```

With `--post-renderer`, `helm list`, `helm uninstall`, etc. all still work.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is that every build of Jenkins CI Job should create docker image with new semantic versioned image tag.
To generate the image tag, you need to tag every git commit with a semantic version which is an increment of the previous commit tag.

For Example :
Your first commit in a git repository master branch will be tagged as 0.0.1 and your docker image tag will be 0.0.1

Then when the CI build runs for the next git commit in master branch, that git commit in the git repository will be tagged as 0.0.2 and your docker image tag will be 0.0.2

Since you have single helm chart for multiple images, your CI Build can then download the latest version of your helm chart, change the docker image tag and upload the helm chart with same helm version.

If you create a new git release branch, then it should be tagged with 0.1.0 and docker image created for this new git release branch should be tagged as 0.1.0

You can use this tag in the Maven pom.xml for Java Applications as well.

Using the docker image tag, developers can checkout the correpsonding git tag to find what is the source code corresponding to that docker image tag. It will help them with debugging and also for providing fixes.

Please also read https://medium.com/@mccode/using-semantic-versioning-for-docker-image-tags-dfde8be06699

Comment: Thanks, Sagar for your suggestion. As I pointed out in my OP, possibility one is unique tags for every build. I'm not sure I like your semver suggestion because we have many, many branches.